# What is the Perrin-Riou logarithm (or regulator)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, l-functions, p-adic-hodge-theory

Recently I've been rewatching some recordings of old talks on L-functions and explicit reciprocity laws (in particular, the series of talks by Loeffler and Zerbes given at this [workshop](https://www.crm.umontreal.ca/2020/Coleman20/horaire_e.html) at the CRM in 2020). By explicit reciprocity laws, we mean relating Euler systems or Galois cohomology to special values of L-functions (or p-adic L-functions), which are related to automorphic forms. One method of doing this mentioned in Loeffler's second talk makes use of the "Perrin-Riou logarithm", which I am unfamiliar with. Does anyone know introductory references for this topic? I am a little more familiar with the Bloch-Kato exponential from p-adic Hodge theory, which apparently this is related to.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I am sure I've already written an expository account of this somewhere, but I looked over the lecture and seminar notes on my webpage and couldn't find it, so I'll write one here instead.

Suppose we start with a $p$-adic representation $V$ of $G_{\mathbb{Q}_p}$, and for simplicity I'll suppose $V$ is crystalline, and let $D = \mathbb{D}_{\mathrm{cris}}(V)$; and I'm also going to suppose that no eigenvalue of $\varphi$ on $D$ is an integer power of $p$.

Then we have the Bloch--Kato exponential
$$exp_V : D / Fil^0 D \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ } H^1_f(\mathbb{Q}_p, V),$$
and we also have the Bloch--Kato dual exponential
$$exp^*_{V^*(1)} : H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p, V) / H^1_f \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ } Fil^0 D$$
defined as the dual of $exp_{V^*(1)}$ with respect to local Tate duality. (Here I'm using the assumption on $\varphi$-eigenvalues to avoid having to distinguish between $H^1_{e}$, $H^1_f$ and $H^1_g$.)

Let me write $\log_V$ for the *inverse* of $\exp_V$, so both $\log$ and $\exp^*$ go *from* some subquotient of $H^1$ and *to* some subquotient of $D$.

The idea of Perrin-Riou's map ("regulator" or "big logarithm" or "big dual exponential" depending on who's writing) is to package together the maps $\log$ and $\exp^*$ **for all twists of $V$ simultaneously**, where the twists are by characters of $\Gamma = Gal(\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^\infty}) / \mathbb{Q}_p) \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^\times$. To make sense of this "packaging together", we note that:

- there is the *Iwasawa cohomology* group $H^1_{\mathrm{Iw}}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty}), V)$, which is a finite-type module over $\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma)$ with the property that for every continuous character $\chi$ of $\Gamma$, there's a natural "specialisation" map
  $$H^1_{\mathrm{Iw}}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty}), V) \otimes_{\Lambda, \chi} \mathbb{Q}_p \xrightarrow{\ \cong\ } H^1(\mathbb{Q}_p, V(\chi^{-1})).$$
  So $H^1_{\mathrm{Iw}}$ packages together the cohomology of all of the twists of $V$.
- For any locally algebraic (equivalently: de Rham) character $\chi$ of $\Gamma$, the space $\mathbb{D}_{\mathrm{dR}}(V(\chi))$ is canonically isomorphic to $D$ [**]. So you can think of $\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma) \otimes D$ as packaging up the $\mathbb{D}_{\mathrm{dR}}(V(\chi))$ for all $\chi$ simultaneously.

So Perrin-Riou (almost [***]) builds a map
$$\mathcal{L}_V : H^1_{\mathrm{Iw}}(\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^\infty}), V) \longrightarrow \Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma) \otimes D,$$
with the property that:

- if you specialise at a character $\chi: x \mapsto x^n \tau(x)$ with $\tau$ of finite order and $n \gg 0$, then the resulting map is (up to an explicit factor) the Bloch--Kato dual exponential for $V(\chi^{-1})$.
- if you specialise at $\chi : x \mapsto x^n \tau(x)$ with $\tau$ of finite order and $n \ll 0$, then the resulting map is (up to an explicit factor) the Bloch--Kato logarithm for $V(\chi^{-1})$.

This is an amazingly cool theorem: it is not so hard to build a map which has one of these two properties, but very hard to show that the *same* map interpolates both $\log$ and $\exp^*$ -- that is (one possible statement of) Perrin-Riou's local reciprocity conjecture, which was an open problem for a good few years until it was resolved by Benois, Berger, and Colmez around 2000.

For further reading, I'd suggest my second paper with Lei and Zerbes, "Coleman maps and the p-adic regulator" (which should be a bit more digestible than our first paper, since we understood the material better by that stage).

**Footnotes**

[*] In this answer, the cyclotomic character has Hodge--Tate weight $+1$ (the convention followed by most, but not all, of the literature).

[**] That is, canonical once we have chosen a basis of $\mathbb{Z}_p(1)$, i.e. a collection of $p^n$-th roots of unity $\zeta_{p^n} \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ with $(\zeta_{p^{n+1}})^p = \zeta_{p^n}$.

[***] "Almost" because it doesn't actually land in $\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma) \otimes D$ but in $\mathcal{H}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma) \otimes D$, where $\mathcal{H}_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma)$ (the locally-analytic distribution algebra) is the completion of $\Lambda_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(\Gamma)$ in some appropriate topology. (Having spent a significant chunk of my career understanding this issue in detail, I can tell you to ignore it with a clean conscience.)

Answer (score 9):

Q:  *Does anyone know introductory references for this topic?*

An exposition of the Perrin-Riou regulator with several worked-out application examples is given in section 2 of [Darmon and Lauder's contribution](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/darmon/pub/Articles/Research/74.DL-PR/DL1.pdf) to Perrin-Riou's Festschrift.

Comment: I'm afraid that the terminology in this area is less consistent than it should be, and what Darmon and Lauder mean by "Perrin-Riou regulator" in this link isn't quite the same thing that Sarah and I were referring to in our CRM lectures (although it's not entirely unrelated).